# Trim spaces in a column

Tags: r, trim

I want to write a query to take count from a Datatable  called "singapore" for a particular condition

```
NAME   COUNTRY     GENDER  OWNHOUSE  NO of houses
X1     SINGAPORE    M       Y        1
X2     SINGAPORE    F       N        0
X3     SINGAPORE    M       N        0
```

Now when I try to take counts from this Dataframe for Gender="F" and ownhouse="Y" it does not take correct count as at some places Gender is written as gender="M  ". 
I want to trim only the column `GENDER`.

Currently I am using below command but it trims all the columns

```
Singapore<- data.frame(lapply(Singapore, trimws), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, since now you reached 15 reputation on Stack Overflow, could you please re-vote up my answer (since you found it helpful) as now your votes can be shown publicly? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trim only a single column just use the function `trimws` on that column only

```
Singapore$GENDER <- trimws(Singapore$GENDER)
```

Answer (score 1):

To trim only the column `GENDER` but keep the data.frame otherwise intact:

```
Singapore$GENDER <- trimws(Singapore$GENDER)
```